# fb.init fb is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a simple video in which at the end it contains a share button , when user clicks a share button a Modal opens with social media icons, eg user can share the video to Facebook, now I want  a callback response from Facebook after the video was shared.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',  
    link: "http://...",
    name: "Some Title",
    caption: "Some Caption",
    description: "Some Description",
    display: "popup",
    Video: "http://..."
}, function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately am getting the following errors

```
fb.init fb is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: _“now I want a callback response from Facebook after the video was shared”_ – which you are likely not going to get. The documentation doesn’t mention any response for this dialog any more. Facebook does not want apps to “reward” users for sharing in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you're not importing the actual library that you are using. I would recommend taking a look how to do that here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

I also notice that you are listing code in upper-case (`FB.init...`) whereas your error is coming in in lower-case (`fb.init...`). Make sure that you are using the same casing as how you are importing it.

Comment: Okay.let me check out,

Comment: This is sample, the real code is here https://meed.audiencevideo.com/. Check the console

Comment: Yep, I can't see where you are importing the library? Simply adding:

`<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js"></script>`

Just after the beginning of the body tag should make it work. Or resolve the error your are seeing anyway.